# I'm having problems connecting from gatling to a rabbit q using gatling-amqp-plugin

Tags: scala, rabbitmq, amqp, gatling

I'm totally stumped here (and scala's cryptic cryptocityness isn't helping :-))

I'm trying to setup gatling tests using rabbitmq (ie I want to push messages into a rabbit q and time how long it takes to appear in a second queue) 
I'm using the [gatling-amqp-plugin](https://github.com/TinkoffCreditSystems/gatling-amqp-plugin) to do this since gatling doesn't natively support amqp.

To make this more "interesting" for me, I don't code in Scala and have never used gatling ....

So I took the "getting started" project [gatling-sbt-plugin-demo](https://github.com/gatling/gatling-sbt-plugin-demo)

Once I was sure that the sample computerdatabase load tests worked, I added a new package to the project and put in the example PublishExample from the amqp project (as well as the required Utils class)

I have a local rabbit docker image running ... this is the docker-compose I used:

```
version: '3'

services:
  rabbi:
    image: rabbitmq:3.6-management
    hostname: "rabbi"
    expose:
      - "5672"
    ports:
      - "15672:15672"
      - "5672:5672"
    environment:
      RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_USER: "USER"
      RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_PASS: "PASS"
      RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_VHOST: "VOST"
```

I then tried running gatling using the PublishExample

```
package rabbit

import io.gatling.core.Predef._
import io.gatling.core.structure.ScenarioBuilder
import ru.tinkoff.gatling.amqp.Predef._
import Utils._
import ru.tinkoff.gatling.amqp.protocol.AmqpProtocolBuilder

import scala.concurrent.duration._

class PublishExample extends Simulation {

  val amqpConf: AmqpProtocolBuilder = amqp
    .connectionFactory(
      rabbitmq
        .host("localhost")
        .port(5672)
        .username("USER")
        .password("PASS")
        .vhost("VOST")
    )
    .usePersistentDeliveryMode

  val scn: ScenarioBuilder = scenario("AMQP test")
    .feed(idFeeder)
    .exec(
      amqp("publish to exchange").publish
        .directExchange("test_queue", "test_key")
        .textMessage("Hello message - ${id}")
        .messageId("${id}")
        .priority(0)
        .property("testheader", "testvalue")
    )

  setUp(
    scn.inject(rampUsersPerSec(1) to 5 during (60 seconds), constantUsersPerSec(5) during (5 minutes))
  ).protocols(amqpConf)
    .maxDuration(10 minutes)

}
```

And this is the error I get

```
:
sbt:gatling-sbt-plugin-demo> gatling:test
[info] Compiling 1 Scala source to<project_folder>/gatling-sbt-plugin-demo/target/scala-2.12/test-classes ...
[info] Compiling 1 Scala source to<project_folder>/gatling-sbt-plugin-demo/target/scala-2.12/gatling-classes ...
Simulation rabbit.PublishExample started...
Uncaught error from thread [GatlingSystem-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-6]: java.lang.reflect.Field.canAccess(Ljava/lang/Object;)Z, shutting down JVM since 'akka.jvm-exit-on-fatal-error' is enabled for ActorSystem[GatlingSystem]
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: java.lang.reflect.Field.canAccess(Ljava/lang/Object;)Z
        at ru.tinkoff.gatling.amqp.request.AmqpProtocolMessage.forceModify(AmqpProtocolMessage.scala:23)
        at ru.tinkoff.gatling.amqp.request.AmqpProtocolMessage.$anonfun$mergeProperties$3(AmqpProtocolMessage.scala:18)
        at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized.foldLeft(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:60)
        at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized.foldLeft$(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:68)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.foldLeft(ArrayOps.scala:198)
  | => gat ru.tinkoff.gatling.amqp.request.AmqpProtocolMessage.$anonfun$mergeProperties$2(AmqpProtocolMessage.scala:18)
        at ru.tinkoff.gatling.amqp.request.AmqpProtocolMessage.$anonfun$mergeProperties$1(AmqpProtocolMessage.scala:14)
        at com.softwaremill.quicklens.package$PathModify.using(package.scala:62)
        at ru.tinkoff.gatling.amqp.request.AmqpProtocolMessage.mergeProperties(AmqpProtocolMessage.scala:16)
        at ru.tinkoff.gatling.amqp.action.AmqpAction.$anonfun$sendRequest$2(AmqpAction.scala:27)
        at io.gatling.commons.validation.Success.map(Validation.scala:45)
        at ru.tinkoff.gatling.amqp.action.AmqpAction.$anonfun$sendRequest$1(AmqpAction.scala:27)
        at io.gatling.commons.validation.Success.flatMap(Validation.scala:46)
        at ru.tinkoff.gatling.amqp.action.AmqpAction.sendRequest(AmqpAction.scala:24)
        at io.gatling.core.action.RequestAction.$anonfun$execute$1(Action.scala:100)
        at io.gatling.commons.validation.Success.flatMap(Validation.scala:46)
        at io.gatling.core.action.RequestAction.execute(Action.scala:97)
        at io.gatling.core.action.RequestAction.execute$(Action.scala:96)
        at ru.tinkoff.gatling.amqp.action.AmqpAction.execute(AmqpAction.scala:12)
        at io.gatling.core.action.Action.$bang(Action.scala:38)
        at io.gatling.core.action.Action.$bang$(Action.scala:38)
        at ru.tinkoff.gatling.amqp.action.AmqpAction.io$gatling$core$action$ChainableAction$$super$$bang(AmqpAction.scala:12)
        at io.gatling.core.action.ChainableAction.$bang(Action.scala:63)
        at io.gatling.core.action.ChainableAction.$bang$(Action.scala:61)
        at ru.tinkoff.gatling.amqp.action.AmqpAction.io$gatling$core$action$ExitableAction$$super$$bang(AmqpAction.scala:12)
        at io.gatling.core.action.ExitableAction.$bang(BlockExit.scala:141)
        at io.gatling.core.action.ExitableAction.$bang$(BlockExit.scala:139)
        at ru.tinkoff.gatling.amqp.action.AmqpAction.$bang(AmqpAction.scala:12)
        at io.gatling.core.action.SingletonFeed$$anonfun$receive$1.applyOrElse(SingletonFeed.scala:71)
        at akka.actor.Actor.aroundReceive(Actor.scala:539)
        at akka.actor.Actor.aroundReceive$(Actor.scala:537)
        at io.gatling.core.akka.BaseActor.aroundReceive(BaseActor.scala:25)
        at akka.actor.ActorCell.receiveMessage(ActorCell.scala:612)
        at akka.actor.ActorCell.invoke(ActorCell.scala:581)
        at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processMailbox(Mailbox.scala:268)
        at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:229)
        at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.exec(Mailbox.scala:241)
        at akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
        at akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
        at akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
        at akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)
[info] Simulation(s) execution ended.
[error] Error during tests:
[error]         Running java with options -classpath <my system class path> 
sbt.ForkMain 51328 failed with exit code 255
[error] (Gatling / test) sbt.TestsFailedException: Tests unsuccessful
[error] Total time: 3 s, completed 26-Apr-2020 22:06:37
sbt:gatling-sbt-plugin-demo>
```

What exatly am I doing wring here? I've tried various changes to the host/vhost/directExchange configs but I cant figure out what I'm doing wrong!!!

Also these are the logs from Rabbit when I run that code above:

```
rabbi_1  |
rabbi_1  | =INFO REPORT==== 26-Apr-2020::21:12:13 ===
rabbi_1  | accepting AMQP connection <0.619.0> (172.20.0.1:56118 -> 172.20.0.2:5672)
rabbi_1  |
rabbi_1  | =INFO REPORT==== 26-Apr-2020::21:12:13 ===
rabbi_1  | connection <0.619.0> (172.20.0.1:56118 -> 172.20.0.2:5672): user 'USER' authenticated and granted access to vhost 'VOST'
rabbi_1  |
rabbi_1  | =WARNING REPORT==== 26-Apr-2020::21:12:14 ===
rabbi_1  | closing AMQP connection <0.619.0> (172.20.0.1:56118 -> 172.20.0.2:5672, vhost: 'VOST', user: 'USER'):
rabbi_1  | client unexpectedly closed TCP connection
```

So I know I am 'connecting' to rabbit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stacktrace is self-explanatory:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: java.lang.reflect.Field.canAccess(Ljava/lang/Object;)Z
        at ru.tinkoff.gatling.amqp.request.AmqpProtocolMessage.forceModify(AmqpProtocolMessage.scala:23)
```

[This method was introduced in Java 9](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/AccessibleObject.html#canAccess-java.lang.Object-), meaning this third-party plugin needs to run with Java 9+ (on contrary to official Gatling components that require Java 8 as of 3.3.1).

Comment: How do I configure that? My $JAVA_HOME is set to corretto_jdk11 and java -version returns 

    openjdk version "11.0.6" 2020-01-14 LTS
    OpenJDK Runtime Environment Corretto-11.0.6.10.1 (build 11.0.6+10-LTS)
    OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Corretto-11.0.6.10.1 (build 11.0.6+10-LTS, mixed mode)


build.sbt, did have a "-target:jvm-1.8" but I commented that out (couldnt figure out what it should be for java 11) but it's still the same error

Comment: I don't know what you do on your machine but you definitively don't execute this code with Java 11. Try printing System.getProperty("java.version") at the beginning of your Simulation and you'll see you're most likely running Java 8.

Comment: you're absolutely right, changing the jvm used to 11 allowed it to work.